# ChartJS 3.x How to place tick label inside graph?

Tags: chart.js

there is a way with ChartJS 3.x to place ticks labels inside chart area like in attached figure?
I had try with negative paddings on ticks but i didnt have success.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative padding is how you do it. Are you sure you put `padding` to the right place?

```
scales: {
          xAxis: {
                type: 'time',
                
                ticks: {
                    display: true,
                    source: 'labels', // get ticks from given labels
                    z: 5, // make sure they are visible
                    padding: -50, // move then ontop of the chart
                },
```

Here is a [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Jesper02/kc58fb9e/1/)

You can read more here: [Tick Configuration.](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/#tick-configuration)

Comment: Thank You, it works fine , i probably missed something in my tests.